# Adding to Column in SQL issues (in photo-gallery website)

Tags: php, database, photo-gallery

I'm building a photography website where I have one page that displays the pictures (bootstrapped and all) and then another page so I can upload new photos (consists of an html page with form and php that runs download code).  In this php page I want to make an SQL addition to my column *name* in database *photos*.  I want to add the file name into the SQL database name so I can later access it in my page displaying the photos and I can get the file name so I can for loop it there for all the pictures in the directory.  The issue I'm having is adding the target file into the *name* and then getting it.  Here's my code for adding the filename:

```
        $link = mysql_connect('meadowebcom.ipagemysql.com', 'lphotos', 'gut2*EMI_12'); 
        if (!$link) { 
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
        } 
        echo 'Connected successfully'; 
        mysql_select_db(photos); 
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `name` (`target_file`) VALUES ('.basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]).');';
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
        mysql_close($conn);
```

I have it display that I am connected but can't add anything.  I haven't even started on getting the file in the other file.  I don't usually do PHP outside of contact and registration forms so any help or any points in the right direction would help.

Comment: In your SQL string, enclose your target_file field value in `''`

Comment: Also for the argument you passed in mysql_select_db(...);

Comment: If you `var_dump($retval)` what do you get? And is the table named `name` ?

Comment: Use $link variable all the time instead instead of $conn

Comment: Also `mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it is removed in PHP 7.0.0.` - You may wanna use mysqli_* next time or PDO.

Comment: I never use the "real" filenames, I guess if it's just you doing the uploads it will be ok.  Just watch out for things like ` ` space, capitalization mistakes like `.JPG` instead of `.jpg`.   What I like to do is hash the file using `sha1` then I save the hash, and the original name.  I display the original name, but I use the hash as the actual filename on disk.  This has the added benefit of telling if a file already exists as you can compare the hashes.